# How to make the keyboard disappear programmatically in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am having trouble getting the keyboard to disappear after entering text. I have many solutions for previous versions of Xcode, but nothing for Xcode 7. My current ViewController.h file looks like:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txtUsername;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txtPassword;

@end
```

My .m file looks like:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize txtUsername;
@synthesize txtPassword;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.txtUsername.delegate = self;
    self.txtPassword.delegate = self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}

@end
```

I have assigned the delegate from the textField to the ViewController as well.

**Update** The View I was working with was not assigned to the ViewController class and therefore did not inherit the textFielfShouldReturn method I needed.

Comment: Have you verified if the `testFieldShouldReturn:` method is actually being called?

Comment: Are your IBOutlets connected?

Comment: @EmilioPelaez I have the outlets connected to the ViewController

Comment: @rmaddy Good catch, after setting a breakpoint it looks like the none of the methods in the .m file are being called.

Comment: If none of the methods (even `viewDidLoad`?) are being called then are you sure you set the view controller's class properly in Interface Builder? Is it set to `ViewController` instead of `UIViewController`?

Comment: This should work. Try to assign your textFields delegates in e.g viewDidAppear. If it will work, then your problem is with delegate assigning too soon. But it should work this way, so you may face different problem and this is only a consequence.

Comment: @JakubTruhlář There is no reason to wait until `viewDidAppear` to set the delegates. `viewDidLoad` is just fine. Something else is wrong.

Comment: @rmaddy viewDidLoad is being called now. textFieldShouldReturn is not

Comment: Then `self.txtUsername` and `self.txtPassword` are `nil`.

Comment: @rmaddy Got it to now call the textFieldShouldReturn method, keyboard still doesn't go away though.

Comment: Got it now! Thanks! @rmaddy

Comment: You should post your own answer explaining what fixed the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
[self.view endEditing:YES];
```

Comment: This shouldn't be needed. The code the OP posted should work.

Comment: Why is an answer that made no attempt to solve the OP's problem getting so many up votes?